# Breakpoint in javascript file never reached in Netbeans JSF app?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I create a breakpoint in a js file part of a web app in Netbeans 7.3 (JSF 2 + Primefaces). Running the app in debug mode, the js file gets executed but the breakpoint never works. Other breakpoints situated in beans are correctly pausing the app for debugging.
Am I missing something obvious about how breakpoints work in javascript files?

Comment: you are missing something about how javascript works.

Comment: your are not being helpful. FYI: http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic53727.html

Comment: So, do you want the Netbeans to handle breakpoints in your javascript code?

Comment: I am asking a question about whether / how this is possible. If not, alternative suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure the alternative suggestions suit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try just released NetBeans 7.4. If you run your project in either NetBeans Embedded browser or in Chrome/Chromium with NB connector, you can debug JS together with Java code and use breakpoints in JS/Java code at the same time